# Error creating new user by Admin

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web application using Form Authentication of Asp.Net with C# and back end Sql Server. Here in my application administrator login and creates new users. I am using the create user wizard under login controls. My problem is when the new user is created by Admin he is automatically logged out and logged in with new user credentials which he has just created. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CreateUserWizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard_members.aspx) has a property called `LoginCreatedUser`.  Set it to false, and this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that wizard is meant for new users so that they can create their own account when they visit the site. it is not intended to work the way your admin is using it.